# Mega Menu and tabs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, megamenu

I need to create a mega menu similar to something used for this [website](http://www.hlgroup.com/en).

this image may give more idea about what  i am trying to achieve.

[image]

So far i am not able to find anything similar to the one used on website.

I came across [jQuery Tools website](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/mouseover.html) with nice tabs. I am trying to integrate this my menu  so that i can get an impression of mega menus.

So far i am not sure how i can integrate it will my navigation and make it look somthing similar to what is show in the image above.

I tried to make changes to css so that `description` div will show up next to sub menu but it is not coming up right.

Help in this regard is appreciated.

MY CODE of **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUGvf/)**

I would appreciate help in this reading.

Comment: please consider adding some code of what you've tried, so we can see what you've tried and help fix your errors

Comment: @samrap, Forgot to add link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JUGvf/